# How to save and assign the value of a function's return after the function is changed?

Tags: python, global-variables

I am trying to save a function's return as a global variable so that I can make use of the return value afterward. However, as I have to use multiple return values of the function, I need to change the function inputs for multiple times. As a result, the function's return also changes in the process, and that I am unable to save the original function's return in the global variable.

For example, from a function called "A", a value of "x" is returned at the first time. Then, I tried to save the value "x" in a global variable called "m". After that, I changed the inputs of function "A" to return another value "y" from the function. However, in this process, the value "x" assigned to the global variable "m" becomes value "y" (because "m" was assigned to be equal to the return of function "A", but not to be equal to value "x").

In this case, I would like to ask the following question:

How can I save the value "x" obtained from function "A" at the first time while getting the value "y" from function "A" at the same time, so that I can make use of "x" and "y" in the later parts of my codes? Thanks a lot.

Comment: store them in a list....or in a dictionary and look them up later.

Answer (score 0):

Store the values in a dictionary.

Like this:

```
GLOBAL_VARIABLE = {}


def calculate_output(input):
    # Calculate and return the output for the given input


def function(input):
    if GLOBAL_VARIABLE.get(input) is None:
        GLOBAL_VARIABLE[input] = calculate_output(input)
    return GLOBAL_VARIABLE[input]
```

Then other parts of your program don't need to access the GLOBAL_VARIABLE directly.

Always call the function and it'll return a pre-calculated output if it exists, otherwise it'll calculate it first and store for later. Using global variables directly is considered bad practice if it can be avoided.

Practical example:

```
MULTIPLY_BY_2_CACHE = {}


def calculate_multiply_by_2(number):
    return number * 2


def multiply_by_2(number):
    if MULTIPLY_BY_2_CACHE.get(number) is None:
        print("Calculating result for %d" % number)
        MULTIPLY_BY_2_CACHE[number] = calculate_multiply_by_2(number)
    else:
        print("Retrieving existing result for %d" % number)
    return MULTIPLY_BY_2_CACHE[number]


print(multiply_by_2(1))
print(multiply_by_2(1))
print(multiply_by_2(2))
print(multiply_by_2(3))
print(multiply_by_2(2))
```

Result:

```
Calculating result for 1
2
Retrieving existing result for 1
2
Calculating result for 2
4
Calculating result for 3
6
Retrieving existing result for 2
4
```

Comment: very nice answer. I would only suggest to replace your `if MULTIPLY_BY_2_CACHE.get(number) is None` to `if number not in MULTIPLY_BY_2_CACHE` as it will be faster and feels more pythonic

Answer (score 0):

you can store all these in a dictionary, so each time you call the function store the result in the dictionary using a label of your choice. In this example I am taking random chars and getting the unicode pointcode of them and storing them in the dictionary. These can then be looked up later using the char.

```
def my_func(char):
    return ord(char)

results = {}
for char in "duthxb":
    results[char] = my_func(char)

print(results)
print(results['t'])
```

**OUTPUT**

```
{'d': 100, 'u': 117, 't': 116, 'h': 104, 'x': 120, 'b': 98}
116
```